# Flat List of Tuples with duplicate "keys" vs Dictionary of Lists C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

When reading mapping data from a config, a system can consume one or more types (not .NET Type)

for example:

- SystemAlpha consumes TypeA
- SystemBeta consumes TypeA
- SystemBeta consumes TypeB

This can be stored in a flat list of type `List<Tuple<string, string>>` as `system, type` pairs which would be very easy to query using LINQ. Querying over which types are consumed by which systems is doable here too, which is a plus. There would be multiple entries of each system if they consumed more than one type (i.e. a duplicate "key"). The downside is the speed of lookup here is `O(n)` (could use a sorted list for `O(log(n))`)

Whereas with a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` would have a single entry per system with a list of consumed types. `O(1)` lookup here but with a disadvantage of not being able to easily query which systems consume a specific type.

The mappings will be small enough (probably) to be okay with having `O(n)` at worst and there's enough memory to go around (in regard to Dictionary overhead).

So what I'm asking is:

1. Which would be the most extendable and reusable? (maybe eventually a large mapping)
2. From a code reading point of view, which would be easiest for someone later to come along and read/use?
3. Am I overthinking this?

(And MultiValueDictionary is not fully released yet)

Comment: How many items are processed from the config file?

Comment: I don't know how you're putting your dictionary/tuples together, but if you're clever, you could probably read the entire lot into an `ILookup` (assuming you can build the entire structure in one go and don't require any modification down after it is built). An `ILookup` is effectively an immutable "multi" dictionary.

Comment: At the moment around 50 from config but that's with the foresight that it could go to 1000+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>`. It gives clearer message to whoever reads your code later.

If you really need *by value* lookup you can have another `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` which will hold the references in oposite direction. Wrapping them both in a class that will keep them in sync will make it easy to assure whenever something changes both collection will reflect the changes.

If number of items is small you could skip the second collection and do a linear lookup to *determine which systems consume specific type*:

```
return dict.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(y => new { x.Key, Value = y })
           .Where(x => x.Value == typeToSearch)
           .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the comparison is not fair in a sense that the two data structures do not put the same limitation on the *data* that you can store: a flat list of tuples allows any number of duplicate "keys", while dictionary does not. This limitation is important: a human reader of your code will read this meaning from a `Dictionary<K,V>`, but not from `List<Tuple<K,V>>`.

Since communicating your intentions to the human readers is one of the most important tasks you have as a designer, using a `Dictionary<K,V>` is a better choice. On top of that, the advantages that you listed in your post apply as well: constant-time lookup will become more important as your mapping grows in size.